# RTRIM increasing scan count

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've inherited a SQL Server 2014 database where all of the columns are of datatype `char` instead of `varchar`.

I'm trying to tune an ITVF that by itself is fine, but when it gets used, the scan count is the equivalent of the number of times it is called within the query, which in my case is 1300.

> Table 'tblOnContainer'. Scan count 1300, logical reads 3900, physical reads 1, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

I am by no means an expert DBE/DBA. From everything I've read high scan counts is a bad thing.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[f_GetOnContainerwithTransit]
    (@ITEM VARCHAR(50),
     @LOCTID VARCHAR(10),
     @Before DATETIME)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
   RETURN 
       (SELECT SUM(QTY) AS OnContainerWithTransit
        FROM tblOnContainer
        WHERE ITEM = @ITEM 
          AND RIGHT(RTRIM(contno), 3) = @LOCTID   -- The last 3 characters indicate what location it is going to, CAL, DAL, BOS, CHI, etc
          AND ADDUSER = 'PRCS' 
          AND status = '' 
          AND ADDDATE <=  DATEADD(d, -(SELECT TOP 1 (AVERAGEDAYSINVIRTUAL + AVERAGEDAYSINHOLDING) 
                                       FROM tblLocations 
                                       WHERE LOCTID = @LOCTID), @Before))
```

I've seen some stuff suggesting the issue may be the RTRIM.

`contno` is of type `char(35)`, and can contain all sorts of values with trailing spaces like

```
'123456789                     '
```

or

```
'0987654321-CAL                     '
```

The execution plan says it's doing an index seek.

I just don't know if this is ok, or if it needs more tuning.

Comment: Why do you need the `RTRIM`? `'123456789             ' = '123456789'`. SQL Server ignores trailing spaces for comparison. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6e651e307947ecb8c614ae0c24ce3122)

Comment: I wish that was the case, but It isn't ignoring them, when I just do the right(contno, 3) =@LOCTID, it only returns records that fill the entire field.

I need it to return all of the records whose last 3 characters match @LOCTID

Comment: I missed the `RIGHT`, apologies, however, if you also needs the right 3 characters the query is *never* going to be SARGable. I t sounds like you're storing the multiple data ppints in a single value and that the right most characters should be in a separate column; either entirely or as a `PERSISTED` computed column.

Comment: I'd love to be able to do that.  I'm dealing with some legacy apps, that we don't have much support for (we're trying to sunset them..... slowly). For the purposes of this query,  I may just create a new column and update it with a trigger, because this query gets called a lot throughout the day.

Comment: Why a `TRIGGER` when you can create a new column with a `PERSISTED` value (which would be far better).If you can create a new column, an populate with `TRIGGER`, you can definitely use a computed `PERSISTED` column.

Comment: Good point, that didn't even cross my mind

Comment: Or persist the column in a view

Comment: So as a follow-up, I tried the computed column, and it worked well for the query.  However, we have a legacy app (that we're slowly trying to sunset) that is causing an issue where when it updates a row, it grabs every column in the table, and send all of them back in the update statement.  So, basically, I had to remove the computed column,